AI SDK Retry Error from official vercel page
I'm using code from the official AI SDK website and this code does NOT run.
This is the error I'm getting: RetryError [AI_RetryError]: Failed after 3 attempts. Last error: Failed to process error response
I just want to run a basic AI program with nextJS.

That is because you need to add in more code to try and fix the problem

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
